# Design an endless scrolling background in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have to build a racing game. For that I am using a road as a background which I need to scroll down and repeat so that the screen always shows a moving road i.e. with respect to the user car the road appears to be moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona/corona-sdk-create-a-side-scroller-from-scratch/ it shows you how to make a continuous running game which includes a continuously moving background.

Comment: Thank you... it served my purpose.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for a future reference, here is the code for a vertical scrolling background:

```
local function moveBg(dt)  
  bg1.y = bg1.y + scrollSpeed * dt
  bg2.y = bg2.y + scrollSpeed * dt
  if (bg1.y - display.contentHeight/2) > display.actualContentHeight then
      bg1:translate(0, -bg1.contentHeight * 2)
  end
  if (bg2.y - display.contentHeight/2) > display.actualContentHeight then
      bg2:translate(0, -bg2.contentHeight * 2)
  end
end
```

And the complete tutorial is here: http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-scrollable-background-in-corona-sdk/